# Best database building practice for members list

Tags: database-design, filtering

I want to make a members database for my association. We are a national organization that is composed by smaller local entities.

I was wondering which practice would be better to organize my database in the mean of speed and overhead:

1. Create one large table with all the members with a "local association" field for filtering.
2. Create many tables, one for each group.

(btw I'm working on joomla, if this could change something)

EDIT: I'll make clearer the structure of the association. One member can be part of only one small local association at time. All member are part of the national association. For every member (and so every associations) the data fields are the same. Comment me if it's still not clear :)

Answer (score 2):

With the limited requirements that you have posted this is how I see it.  It is a third alternative because the 2 options you posted really are not appropriate for a DB.

[image]

You describe 3 different entities (Member, Group (Assoc.), Address (Location)) and per rules of normalization you need to separate those appropriately.  If you keep everything in only 1 or 2 tables you will have duplicates throughout your DB.  Personally I agree with Thomas here and would look into incorporating the second option that I posted.

I just gave a basic table structure, again not understanding your full requirements, so please adjust the Relationship Cardinality as you see fit for your requirements.  The most important part of my answer that I am trying to stress is normalize appropriately. Contrary to what others say about simplicity you can't get any more simple then having a properly set up database that in turn is properly normalized.

Comment: 1+ for the complexity of the answer for sure! As i pointed out before members can be part of only one local association at time. I will edit my question to make it more clear. thanks!

Comment: @Bakaburg In that case I have to ask can a Member exist outside of a Group?  If so the 2nd model will work just change the Cardinality on the Member::MemberGroup relation.  The first model requires that a Member has to be added as part of a group when they are added to the system (barring you do things right and not allow NULLS).  I would not recommend such a constraint in this type of scenario though.

Comment: No, a member has to be part of one local group. For example: a citizen is a citizen of his city, but also of the country, but not of other cities of the country. There's no need to put "address", the name of the local group is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are tracking the same fields for all members, regardless of local association, I would lean towards one table for all members. This will significantly lower your maintenance overhead when you add/remove local associations.

If different local associations track significantly different information about members, then you may need to reconsider this recommendation a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a third alternative: a table of members, a table of associations and a table that associates the two together. In this way, the same person can be part of multiple associations without having to duplicate their information.

Comment: Thanks, but this cannot be the case, members can be part of one local association at time, sorry for not pointing it out :)

Comment: @Bakaburg - How is the rule with respect to a single association enforced since I'm assuming these associations are separate legal entities?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one large table.  Even if splitting it up were theoretically faster, you'd lose a lot of advantages in terms of simplicity. For instance, in relation to speed, consider the simplicity of tuning and optimizing queries against one table as opposed to 10 tables.

Also I'm concerned that if you have multiple tables, you would be having a lot of redundancy. So by all means, if you do split, try to minimize redundancy and use relationships to avoid having to maintain tons of almost identical tables.

Comment: If you are going to have one large table might as well just use a spreadsheet.  Multiple tables will actually reduce redundancy and eliminate the chance of nulls.